# Sorting by custInvoiceJour.Dimension

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

How does one sort invoice values by dimensions ?

Lets say that I wanted to loop through all of the records in the period 01.01.2014 to 05.01.2014 and sum up the total invoiceAmount for each dimension.

If I were writing this in C# I would probably just make a directory and do a ForEach on the dataset and check if the key exists in the directory if it does I would add to the value if it does not exist I would add a new key to the directory.

But i am unsure how to do this in X++

```
while select custInvoiceJour
    where   custInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate >= 01\01\2014
    &&      custInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate < 04\01\2014
{
    // Here I would need some kind of container or other method of
    // working with the data
    info(strFmt("Dimension %2", custInvoiceJour.Dimension[2]));
}
```

Comment: Is version AX 2012 R2 in the tags correct? Because in this version there is no field `Dimension` in table `CustInvoiceJour`. In version 2009 this field still existed, but it was replaced with field `DefaultDimension`, which works quite differently. Take a look at the white paper [Implementing the Account and Financial Dimensions Framework (White paper) [AX 2012]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272858.aspx)

Comment: This is not an X++ answer but...  The financial guys love it when you [deploy the default Analysis Services cube](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309683.aspx).